# Legend order for proximate layout

Tags: highcharts

I have a chart with right aligned legend and proximate layout. Proximate setting works great for most of the cases, however we noticed that sometimes the legend items order isn't inline with the latest data point which makes reading of the chart a bit confusing.
We've been able to replicate the issue in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hjvod7bc/).

Please do not adjust chart width. Last data points need to be close to each other and multiline legend labels should be preserved. Appreciate if someone can look into it.

Below is the code from the fiddle:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
      styledMode: true,
    },
    legend: {
      align: 'right',
      layout: 'proximate',
      width: '30%'
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            pointStart: 2010
        }
    },

    series: [
      {
        name: 'Installation',
        data: [43934, 52503, 57177, 69658, 97031, 119931, 137133, 39389]
    },  {
        name: 'Manufacturing',
        data: [24916, 24064, 29742, 29851, 32490, 30282, 38121, 39388]
    },   {
        name: 'Sales & Distribution',
        data: [11744, 17722, 16005, 19771, 20185, 24377, 32147, 39387]
    },  {
        name: 'Project Development',
        data: [null, null, 7988, 12169, 15112, 22452, 34400, 39386]
    }, {
        name: 'Other',
        data: [12908, 5948, 8105, 11248, 8989, 11816, 18274, 39385]
    },
    ]

});
```

Thank you in advance!

Adding a visual to better describe the problem.
[image]

Comment: I am afraid that I don't understand what is wrong with this chart. Could you explain? And describe what is the wanted result?

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to look into it. 
In the chart I shared above the legend order should go as following: [Installation, Manufacturing, Sales & Distribution, Project Development, Other] if reading from top to bottom. However, you may see that order isn't preserved and the top item is `Sales&Distribution`. When legend items do not have multiline labels the order is correctly preserved - [example](https://jsfiddle.net/2uemx0vg/). The q is if it possible to preserve right legend order with proximate layout for multiline legend labels. Thank you!

Comment: I added a visual into description for more clarity. Hope it make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the explanation in the comment section. Try to use this legend config to solve the issue:

```
  legend: {
    align: 'right',
    layout: 'vertical',
    width: '30%',
    verticalAlign: 'middle',
  },
```

Demo; https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/20k9usfp/

Comment: Thanks for the workaround, however `vertical` layout doesn't work for us. We very much need a `proximate` setting. For instance if you switch the order of `Installation` and `Manufacturing` series, the first item will be `Manufacturing` were is a desired result `Installation` to be on the top, since it has a higher last data point- [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ptcLzx2w/)

Comment: I see, I am afraid that it might be a bug related to using styled mode, without it everything works as expected: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/mk8hcpeL/ Could you report this bug on the Highcharts Github issue channel? https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues